# Scala/Java - library to parse some text and remove punctuation?

Tags: java, scala, text, punctuation

I am using a `BreakIterator` implementation in Java to remove punctuation from a String. I need to rewrite this in Scala, so I figured this might be a good opportunity to replace it with a nicer library (my implementation is quite naive, and I'm sure it fails for edge cases).

Does any such library exist that might of be use?

Edit: Here is my quick solution in Scala:

```
  private val getWordsFromLine = (line: String) => {
    line.split(" ")
        .map(_.toLowerCase())
        .map(word => word.filter(Character.isLetter(_)))
        .filter(_.length() > 1)
        .toList
  }
```

And given this `List[String]` (one for each line... and yes... that IS the Bible - it makes good test cases):

> THE SECOND BOOK OF MOSES, CALLED EXODUS
>
> CHAPTER 1 1 Now these [are] the names of the children of Israel, which
>   came into Egypt; every man and his household came with Jacob. 2
>   Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and Judah, 3 Issachar, Zebulun, and Benjamin, 4
>   Dan, and Naphtali, Gad, and Asher.

you get a `List[String]` like so:

```
List(the, second, book, of, moses, called, exodus, chapter, now, these, are, the, names, of, the, children, of, israel, which, came, into, egypt, every, man, and, his, household, came, with, jacob, reuben, simeon, levi, and, judah, issachar, zebulun, and, benjamin, dan, and, naphtali, gad, and, asher)
```

Comment: Why not use your Java implementation in Scala? The two are interoperable. You can still add some Scala goodies around the Java API to make it easier/nicer to use.

Comment: I could. I just didn't want to have to rewrite it if I didn't have to.

Comment: Illustrating what you are looking for by providing examples would help. From your current description I'd say that a regex should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case, I'd go with regex.

```
def toWords(lines: List[String]) = lines flatMap { line =>
  "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn line map (_.toLowerCase)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using regular expressions. It does not yet filter single-character words, though.

```
val s = """
THE SECOND BOOK OF MOSES, CALLED EXODUS

CHAPTER 1 1 Now these [are] the names of the children of Israel,
which came into Egypt; every man and his household came with
Jacob. 2 Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and Judah, 3 Issachar, Zebulun,
and Benjamin, 4 Dan, and Naphtali, Gad, and Asher.
"""

/* \p{L} denotes Unicode letters */
var items = """\b\p{L}+\b""".r findAllIn s

println(items.toList)
  /* List(THE, SECOND, BOOK, OF, MOSES, CALLED, EXODUS,
          CHAPTER, Now, these, are, the, names, of, the,
          children, of, Israel, which, came, into, Egypt,
          every, man, and, his, household, came, with,
          Jacob, Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and, Judah,
          Issachar, Zebulun, and, Benjamin, Dan, and,
          Naphtali, Gad, and, Asher)
  */

/* \w denotes word characters */
items = """\b\w+\b""".r findAllIn s
println(items.toList)
  /* List(THE, SECOND, BOOK, OF, MOSES, CALLED, EXODUS,
          CHAPTER, 1, 1, Now, these, are, the, names, of,
          the, children, of, Israel, which, came, into,
          Egypt, every, man, and, his, household, came,
          with, Jacob, 2, Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and, Judah,
          3, Issachar, Zebulun, and, Benjamin, 4, Dan, and,
          Naphtali, Gad, and, Asher)
  */
```

Word boundaries `\b` are described [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/), the Javadoc for regular expressions are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).